# What is the difference between ～みたい and ～らしい when expressing similarity or resemblance?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

According to [this HiNative question](https://hinative.com/en-us/questions/5343), `～みたいだ` tends to be used subjectively, whereas `～らしい` tends to be used more objectively.

This seems to indicate that the difference is the same as that between the 2 senses of `～そうです`, i.e. deduction vs hearsay.

Is the distinction as simple as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. みたい is usually about your perception or opinion. らしい conveys indirect information that you heard, saw or read somewhere.

### みたい

#### ~ looks like

Used when *you* think (subjectively) something looks or is like so. Used very often.

> お母{かあ}さんは怒{おこ}っている**みたい**だ。
>
> 彼{かれ}のことを好{す}きになってしまった**みたい**だ。
>
> そのチケットは[売{う}り切{き}れ](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%A3%B2%E3%82%8A%E5%88%87%E3%82%8C)てしまった**みたい**だ。

### らしい

#### ~ appears to be, seems that, I hear ~

Used when reporting that something looks or seems like so according to what someone else said, or something you read. It's more objective than みたい.

> お母{かあ}さんは怒{おこ}っているらしい、**弟{おとうと}がそう言{い}っていた。**
>
> イタリアまで飛行機{ひこうき}で15時間{じかん}かかる**らしい**。
>
> 新{あたら}しいお店{みせ}が来月{らいげつ}オープンする**らしい**。

#### ~like, ideal characteristic of something

Another interesting use of らしい is to express that something is the archetypal rendering of a definition or concept. You use it when someone or something looks like the best representation of what is expected.

In other words, that something is just what it *should* or *ought* to be (according to convention / tradition / common knowledge, etc). For example, 男{おとこ}らしい means *masculine* / *manly* and carries a positive connotation, whereas 男っぽい is just mannish or *kinda like man*, also it isn't clear whether it's meant as a compliment or insult. Another example is 子供{こども}っぽい *childish*.

This is a good example:

> お兄{にい}さん**らしく**しなさい。
>
> *Act more like a good older brother!* or *That's not how a good brother should behave!*